# Minimising the integral of two functions

Tags: real-analysis

I've been given two functions: $f,g: [a,b] \to \mathbb R$. I have to minimize 
$$t\mapsto \int_a^b (f(x)-tg(x))^2 dx.$$

I have been asked to do this in order to show

$$\int_a^b  (f(x)g(x))^2 dx \le \int_a^b f(x)^2 dx\int_a^b g(x)^2dx.$$

I haven't been able to get very far, as I keep getting confused. I assume I have to find the derivative of the original integral, but I don't really know how. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Is the integral then $\int_a^b (f(x)-t g(x))^2 dx$?

Comment: Yeah, that's right

Answer (score 3):

If the original integral is $$I=\int_a^b (f(x)-tg(x))^2 dx$$

then you can rewrite it as

$$\begin{align}I&=\int_a^b (f^2(x) - 2f(x)g(x)\cdot t + g^2(x)\cdot t^2)dx\\
&= \int_a^b f^2(x) - t\cdot 2\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx + t^2\cdot \int_a^b g^2(x)dx\end{align}$$

so basically, your function is of the form $A t^2 + Bt + C$ for some constants $A,B,C\in\mathbb R$. You probably know how to minimise this function.

Comment: Minor typo:  You might want to square $t$ in the first line of your second equation.  Great way of answering, though, leaving the rest to the asker.

Comment: @Michael Typo corrected. Just for future reference, you can easily edit and correct such typos yourself, as long as you are 100% they are typos.